# Get the file name of the current log file Enterprise Library 5.0

Tags: c#, logging, enterprise-library-5, logging-application-block

In MS Enterprise Library 5.0, Logging application block, at runtime, Can I get the name of the log  file (Flat File Listener) to which the log is going to?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: I tried the various methods available on the LogWriter, and tried finding on the internet if somebody had the same question..

Answer (score 2):

You can get that information by using the configuration objects:

```
IConfigurationSource configSource = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
var logSettings = configSource.GetSection(LoggingSettings.SectionName) as LoggingSettings;

var flatFileTraceListener = logSettings.TraceListeners
    .First(t => t is FlatFileTraceListenerData) as FlatFileTraceListenerData;

string fileName = flatFileTraceListener.FileName;
```

This assumes that you are interested in the first trace listener that is a FlatFileTraceListener.  If you wanted to get the trace listener by type and name then you could do that too:

```
IConfigurationSource configSource = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
var logSettings = configSource.GetSection(LoggingSettings.SectionName) as LoggingSettings;

var flatFileTraceListener = logSettings.TraceListeners
    .FirstOrDefault(t => t is FlatFileTraceListenerData && t.Name == "Flat File Trace Listener")
    as FlatFileTraceListenerData;

string fileName = flatFileTraceListener.FileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Config is no problem.
After Change the filename property  **aaa.log** -> **bbb.log** the Logger not Write in the new Filename.
The changed config must saved/activated (?) or the Logger must new Initialized..!??

```
    IConfigurationSource configSource = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
    var logSettings = configSource.GetSection(LoggingSettings.SectionName) as LoggingSettings;

    var rollFileTraceListener = logSettings.TraceListeners
        .FirstOrDefault(t => t is RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData && t.Name == "RollingFlatFileTraceListener")
        as RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData;

    string fileName = rollFileTraceListener.FileName;
    rollFileTraceListener.FileName = fileName.Replace("aaa", "bbb");

    LogWriterFactory f = new LogWriterFactory(configSource);
    f.Create();
    Logger.Reset();
    LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
    logEntry.Message = $"{DateTime.Now} Count:{333}";
    logEntry.Categories.Clear();
    logEntry.Categories.Add("General");

    Logger.Write(logEntry);
```